# This is a Monoid instance I wrote for a Tree data type. Is this the most terse way to express mappend?

Tags: haskell

Here's my type:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

Here's the instance declaration for Monoid:

```
instance (Monoid a) => Monoid (Tree a) where
    mempty = Empty
    mappend Empty Empty = Empty
    mappend Empty t = t
    mappend t Empty = t
    mappend (Node val ta tb) (Node val' ta' tb') = (Node (mappend val val') (mappend ta ta') (mappend tb tb'))
```

This compiles, but it was tedious to write and very repetitive. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: In addition to @Garrison's answer it might be nicer to use the infix `<>` operator in the last line in the place of `mappend`.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove `mappend Empty Empty = Empty` because that case will be caught by `mappend Empty t = t`.

```
instance (Monoid a) => Monoid (Tree a) where
    mempty = Empty
    mappend Empty t = t
    mappend t Empty = t
    mappend (Node val ta tb) (Node val' ta' tb') = (Node (mappend val val') (mappend ta ta') (mappend tb tb'))
```